# How can ichange a virtualbox configuration using docker-machine

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, virtualbox, docker-machine

Hi I have created a virtual box with certain params (number of cpus memory etc), can I change those settings anywhere without having to re-create the VM ? If I use docker-machine create then I'm going to have to re-do eveything in that image again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah you can.  Just load up the UI and you'll see your docker machine VM.

Change memory, add storage, change CPUs, etc. You need to make sure your VM is not running when you make any config changes.

[image: VBox]

Answer (score 0):

Docker machines stores the configuration under

`~/.docker/machine/machines/default/config.json`

You can edit the file manually and restart the vm to apply the changes.

E.g.

If you want to increase the base memory from 1 GB to 2 GB, change `"Memory":1024` into `"Memory":2048`

After you make the changes, save the file and restart the docker machine using.

`docker-machine restart <machine-name>`